# Question about responsive design on Android apps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, responsive-design

Let's say I'm working with four different folders for different screen sizes. These folders are layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-720dp.

What I am not clear about is, do I have to make modifications to the layout code for each of the previous directories, or would it simply be to copy and paste the same code in each of those directories?

My main question would be above all how to manage the height and width of the different views of each layout... I would have to give it a specific width and height for each of the sw directories or limit myself to assigning "wrap_content" to the height and width of the views in the different sw directories regardless of the minimum screen size?

Here is an example of the doubt I have between two options:

---

OPTION 1:

layout-sw480dp

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp" />
```

layout-sw600dp

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp" />
```

layout-sw720dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp" />
```

---

OPTION 2:

layout-sw480dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

layout-sw600dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

layout-720dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

My question is, which of the 2 options would be correct when applying a responsive design?

I wanna solve a doubt about responsive design for Android apps.

Comment: Option 2 dear.  responsive design for Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a custom toolbar*

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        />
</LinearLayout>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txt_title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
     android:fontFamily="@font/ff_bold"
     android:text="@string/help_support"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ff_regular"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:text="View tickets"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/></LinearLayout>
```